# Freshly Built PC Won't Post

Tags: boot, desktop-computer, computer-building, post

I am having an issue with the PC that I'm building: it's not posting and there's no video output. When I turn on the PC a yellow/orange light appears on the motherboard; there are no beeps, the fans work, and the case LED's work. When I try to turn off the PC via the power button, the lights start flashing and PC won't turn off. I don't know what is happening, but I have a feeling it's the RAM. I've already tried all the RAM slots and removing all components (even GPU & RAM, same problem). I have tried to use the CMOS from my old motherboard (even though the Gigabyte motherboard is brand new) but the same issue is happening. Display is definitely connected to the GPU.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I was able to solve my issues by buying new Corsair Vengeance RAM.

My PC:

> Ryzen 7 2700
>   Gigabyte B450M DS3H
>   EVGA GTX 1060 6 GB
>   Samsung 1 x 16 DDR4 2400 MHz **Edit: I was able to solve my issues by buying new Corsair Vengeance RAM**
>   PSU is a Corsair VS450 (450W)
>   1 TB Western Digital HDD
>   2 TB Toshiba HDD
>   Sandisk 240 GB SSD

Comment: 450W is probably not enough.

Comment: If the motherboard has integrated video out, try unplugging the GeForce GTX 1060 and connect display to motherboard. That would reduce the power drain and eliminate the video card and drivers, to see if either are an issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, I checked PCPartPicker and the total only adds up to ~310W. The motherboard doesn't have integrated video out as far as I'm aware, but I've used the GPU on another system and it works 100%. Some further would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10#kf) it appears the board does have integrated video outputs, the DVID & HDMI.  Try running it without the video card.  Otherwise, update the BIOS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, I've tried to use the integrated GPU, but I face the same issue. I'm not able to update the BIOS as the computer doesn't boot, even into BIOS. Many thanks.

Comment: Hey everyone, I was able to solve my issues by buying new Corsair Vengeance RAM. Many thanks.

Comment: Post this as an answer down below and then mark it as such.

Comment: In the "good old times" the PC speaker would beep on RAM errors ;-) However it requires some programming skill to make the CPU create beeps completely without RAM...